# Too many open files error but lsof shows a legal number of open files

Tags: java, linux

My Java program is failing with

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Too many open files
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
        at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:883)...
```

Here are key lines from `/etc/security/limits.conf`. They set the max files for a user at 500k:

```
root                     soft    nofile          500000
root                     hard    nofile          500000
*                        soft    nofile          500000
*                        hard    nofile          500000
```

I ran `lsof` to to count the number of files open -- both globally and by the jvm process. I examined counters in `/proc/sys/fs`. All seems OK. My process only has 4301 files open and the limit is 500k:

```
:~# lsof | wc -l
5526
:~# lsof -uusername | wc -l
4301
:~# cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
744363
:~# cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
744363
:~# cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr
4736    0       744363
```

This is an Ubuntu 11.04 server. I have even rebooted so I am positive these parameters are being used.

I don't know if it's relevant, but the process is started by an upstart script, which starts the process using setuidgid, like this:

```
exec setuidgid username java $JAVA_OPTS -jar myprogram.jar
```

What I am missing?

Comment: Try updating your heap space and giving it a larger max. Not sure why the two would be related, but I've hit that error for a myriad of different issues.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. But it's already -Xmx5800m :)

Comment: some where in the process tree are you setting new limits using ulimit?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It turns out the problem was that my program was running as an upstart init script, and that the `exec` stanza does not invoke a shell. `ulimit` and the settings in limits.conf apply only to user processes in a shell.

I verified this by changing the exec stanza to

```
exec sudo -u username java $JAVA_OPTS -jar program.jar
```

which runs java in username's default shell. That allowed the program to use as many open files as it needs.

I [have seen it mentioned](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/how-to-set-ulimits-for-a-specific-user-with-no-login-shell-587591/) that you can also call `ulimit -n` prior to invoking the command; for an upstart script I think you would use a `script` stanza instead.

I found a better diagnostic than `lsof` to be `ls /proc/{pid}/fd | wc -l`, to obtain a precise count of the open file descriptor. By monitoring that I could see that the failures occurred right at 4096 open fds. I don't know where that 4096 comes from; it's not in /etc anywhere; I guess it's compiled into the kernel.

Answer (score 4):

I have this snippet of bash at the top of a server creation script:

```
# Jack up the max number of open file descriptors at the kernel
echo "fs.file-max = 1000000" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
invoke-rc.d procps start

# Increase max open file descriptors for this process
ulimit -n 1000000

# And for future ones as well
cat >> /etc/profile <<LIMITS
ulimit -n 1000000
LIMITS
cat >> /etc/security/limits.conf <<LIMITS
root - nofile 1000000
LIMITS
```